# Chinese Pottery, please help

Tags: translation

Please could someone translate / explain what this means? It is on the side of a teapot from Hong Kong. I understand that it may be explaining it's origin and not mean anything by itself, but any help would be fantastic.

[image: teapot inscription]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 綠衣初發江南春

- 綠衣(green clothes)
- 初發 (first start)
- 江南春 (Jiangnan's  spring)

The land begin to put on green clothes (refers to the landscape is starting to cover with spring plants) indicates it is Jiangnan's early spring

> 遠浦輕帆萬里程

- 遠浦 (faraway port)
- 輕帆 (light sail = small boat)
- 萬里程 (ten thousand miles journey = very long journey)

At a faraway port, in a small boat, embark on a long journey

*If it was a 七言绝句 (seven-character quatrains), there would be two more verses in it. It looks more like a 對聯 (couplet) as it is now*

Note: a small boat is not capable of long-distance sea-going. This long journey is most likely on a river

Comment: Definitely NOT a couplet 對聯. The parts of speech do not match.

Comment: let's try to make it one. how about 青衫遲慕故國秋

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but 江南 / 故國 there's still some room for improvement.  Also, 遲慕? 遲暮？

Comment: how about 綠衣初發江南春; 青衫遲暮宋國秋

Comment: 平仄不叶。Not to be picky but, among others,「春」and「秋」have the same tone. It doesn't follow the rule, which is 仄起平落. According to the rule, 春 can only be used in the second half, not the first half, of the couplet. So, as it is, there is no way you can make a couplet out of it.

Comment: 小人不才，不過這原本就不是對聯，再加兩句使它成為七言绝句的四行詩還合理一點。有那位文士有詩興？(I Googled the first two verses but can't find anything online)

Comment: Yes, parts of speech aside, the tones are also quite mixed up. 平仄 is important in couplets. Examples: 衣 / 衫 are both 平聲. 發 / 暮 both 仄聲, so that's a no-no

Comment: 小人不才,谦虚是休  :)  Perhaps someone like to complete this humble offering?   再次逗留大漠东，................................ ?

Comment: can it be 何時去到大道中?

Comment: Yes, of course it can be. There is no such thing as "wrong" in 詩興? Thanks for responding, much appreciated. I wonder what other knowledgeable contributors make of that. As we are just amateurs, (at least I am), fooling around while trapped at home by C-19 with nowhere safe to go, I was thinking of 走来走去一场空, LOL.

Comment: I am not even an amateur, I am a 門外漢